# Startup Performance: Is it possible to cache/preload a android app via a background task?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-background

I need to improve my apps startup time, that for I already reduced the work that is done at onCreate...() to a minimum.

The app still takes too long to startup and I am wondering if it is possible to use something like a background task to preload the application or just its activity/views/fragments to reduce the startup time like e.g. Spotify does on Windows.

Like I said, startup performance is crucial with my application, I appreciate any hints on improvement.

Comment: Use Traceview and determine exactly where your time is being spent.

Comment: I need to go beyond optimization, as I target a realtime start of my app.

Comment: Android is not a real-time operating system.